# wmii configuration script for Pidgin notification

Tags: pidgin

I am new to [wmii](http://wmii.suckless.org/). Could anybody kind enough to share his configuration script with a nice status bar that could display notifications from Pidgin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got the notification work for Pidgin.
First, 'command-notification' plugin from Pidgin site, [download](http://gnet.homelinux.com/files/command-notification-0.1.tar.gz)

Then configure the plugin execute a shell script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

owins=$(wmiir ls /client | grep -v -e 'sel')
for owin in $owins; do
  wincount=$(wmiir read /client/$owin/props | grep -c -e "Pidgin:Pidgin")
  if [ $wincount != 0 ]; then
    wmiir xwrite /client/$owin/ctl Urgent off
    wmiir xwrite /client/$owin/ctl Urgent on
    wmiir xwrite /event Notice "You have new message!"
  fi
done
```